# Issue with variable scoping (I think)

Tags: python-2.7

Ok. Pulling my hair out on this one. I write code like this all day long and can't for the life of me see why this is doing this. Maybe I need sleep.

My code:

```
    gsamp       = 0     # good samples
    zsamp       = 0     # zero samples
    nsamp       = 0     # null samples
    rtotal      = 0 
    rtotalltms  = 0 
    pctltms     = 0.0 
    peakh       = 0 
    peakl       = 0 

    for sample in self.rawdata:
        if "data" not in sample['data']:
            nsamp += 1
            continue
        if not bool(sample['data']['data']):
            nsamp += 1
            continue
        rtotal += sample['data']['value']
        gsamp += 1
        # If I print gsamp here it shows it being correctly incremented
        for entry in sample['data']['data']:
            if int(entry['key']) <= thresh:
                rtotalltms += entry['value']
            if gsamp == 1:
                print "DEBUG gsamp=%d" % gsamp
                peakh = int(entry['key'])
                peakl = int(entry['key'])
                continue
            if int(entry['key'] > peakh):
                peakh = int(entry['key'])
                continue
            if int(entry['key'] < peakl):
                peakl = int(entry['key'])
                continue
```

I should only ever see that debug line printed 1 time. But for some reason gsamp is being locally scoped or something.

When I run this code with a data set of 30 samples, I see that debug line printed 30 times with gsamp = 1.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are incrementing `gsamp` in your top loop, as you loop through `sample.rawdata`, but then you hit a second loop, `sample['data']['data']`. This is where the debug statement is getting printed.

If you remove the rest of the code, you can see what's going on:

```
[...]

gsamp += 1
    # If I print gsamp here it shows it being correctly incremented
    for entry in sample['data']['data']:
        if int(entry['key']) <= thresh:
            rtotalltms += entry['value']
        if gsamp == 1:
            print "DEBUG gsamp=%d" % gsamp

            [...]
```

Comment: But gsamp is still in scope, why would it not use the same gsamp as the next higher level in the loop?